# Finding head - Standard vs. Binarized Tree

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using Stadford Core NLP library (with java) in order to get parsed lexicalized trees (including phrase-structure and dependency).

**TL;DR; :** Head-finder (possibly) doesn't handles correctly binarized artificial nodes (@XX) in the StanfordCoreNlp output parse tree and also doesn't find the head word of the root of the output.

**The gory details:**

I am using the StanfordCoreNlp and then reading annotations in order to find constituency, sentiment, dependency and so forth. I initialize the pipeline and use it as follows:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, depparse, sentiment");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

I parse a text and traverse the sentences in it to find the heads:

```
public processText(text) {
    HeadFinder hf = new CollinHeadFinder(); // or one of descendants
    Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(myText);
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
        Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
        determineHeads(tree, null, hf)
    }
}

private determineHeads(Tree node, Tree parent, HeadFinder hf) {
    Tree head = node.headTerminal(headFinder, parent);
    // do something with head
    for(Tree child : node.children()) {
         dfs(child, node, headFinder);
    }
}
```

As a preface to the question, it is important to take into account that the parse tree returned by the **pipeline** is binarized, breaking nodes who has more than two daughters into a sub-tree chain, adding artificial node with only binary derivation (see image 1). In addition, "redundant" nodes are omitted (e.g. the *S* under *ROOT*, see image 2).

**Image 1 : Tree Binarization**

[image: Standard Binzarized Tree]

**Image 2 : Fixed tree ROOT**

[image: Fixed Tree ROOT]

Now to the questions:

1. it seems that there is something going wrong with the head-finder when handling binarized tree. It appears that if one of the daughters is an artificial node it is not handled well which causes the wrong head to be selected. For example, consider the first @NP node in the left branch which selects "quick" as opposed to selecting the noun "fox". In comparison you can see that using the same mechanism (`tree.headTerminal(...)`) on a standard (non-binarized) parse sub-tree yields the expected results (I added the head word in red). My instructor and I stepped through the code and it seem not to handle the @CX well. In AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineNonTrivialHead, there is reference only to the mother's having "@", which I assume should be ok in case recursive calls are being made for for some reason, it seems not to yield the expected result.

[image: Head Terminal in Standard vs. Binarized]

2. In the Tree returned by the pipeline, I am not able to use head-finder. The last nodes which I can get head for are the NP and VP and the function call on the root give me an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' exception. No head rule defined for ROOT using class edu.stanford.nlp.trees.CollinsHeadFinder in (ROOT
>     (NP (DT The)
>       (@NP (JJ quick)
>         (@NP (JJ brown) (NN fox))))
>     (@S
>       (VP (VBD jumped)
>         (PP (IN over)
>           (NP (DT the)
>             (@NP (JJ fat)
>               (@NP (JJ lazy) (NN dog))))))
>       (. .)))

Am I doing assuming something wrong? Does these work as expected? Any ideas how to get the head of the root?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @user1802486 - sorry this was too long ago that I no longer remember